# How to know when to stop reading the file?

Tags: c

Few lines from the file I am trying to work with:

> ```
> f  1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
> f  1/1/1 3/3/3 4/4/4
> f  5/5/5 2/2/2 1/1/1
> ```

My code:

```
else if (fileText[0] == 'f' && fileText[1] == ' ') {
    char* tmp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
    tmp = fileText;

    obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].size = 0;

    //declaration of useful temporary parameters
    char *token = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    token = strtok(tmp, " "); //take the f from the line, start the strtok process with tmp to be used as NULL afterwards
    int i = 0; //counter for the temp array
    int flag = 0;

    //taking the int values from an f line
    while (flag == 0) {

        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
        obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex[i] = atoi(token);

        obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].size++;

        printf("\ntemp[%d]: %d \n", i ,obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex[i]);
        obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex = (int*) realloc(obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].vertex, sizeof(int) * (obj->faces[obj->numberOfFaces].size + 1));

        i++;
        if (strtok(NULL, " ")) { //skip the part until a space appears
            printf("%s", token);
            continue;
        }
        flag = 1; // flag turns 1 after the whole line has been read
    }

    obj->numberOfFaces++;

    //reallocating memory
    obj->faces = (Face*) realloc(obj->faces, sizeof(Face) * (obj->numberOfFaces + 1));
}
```

I am basically trying to read an .obj file and allocate the information from it to the right places, fileText contains the string from a single line (f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 for instance).
Since the file may contain more than 3 numbers at a time (f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4), I need to find a way to stop the program and exit from this line, thus I need to find an indication for it.

this is the console after a run attempt, exit value -1:

```
temp[0]: 1 
1
temp[1]: 2 
2
temp[2]: 3
```

seems like it terminates after the third `printf`, but I'm really unsure what's going on here.

Comment: `fgets()` reads a whole line, stopping at, and including, the `'\n'` (provided you supply a large enough buffer).

Comment: `tmp = fileText;` reassigns the pointer, leaking the allocation you just did on the line above. Did you mean to do `strcpy(tmp, fileText)`?

Comment: Do you want to discard the whole line if the line has more than 3 numbers, or read these 3 numbers and discard the rest of the line?

Comment: I used the fileText instead of copying it into tmp before, and it did the same thing.
I want to read numbers until i reach an area with '\n' or just a blank area, since some f's contain 4-5 numbers.

Comment: You're also leaking the `token` string. You really need to learn how to properly copy strings.

Comment: `if (strtok(NULL, " "))` will skip over all the other `/` characters in the field, it won't tell you if the next delimiter is space or `/`.

Comment: I only need the first number from each section, that is why I want to skip to the next space, I agree that copying strings is really not my strength.

Comment: So your question is just how to tell when you've read all the fields? `strtok()` will return `NULL` when you're done.

Comment: @Barmar, changing the ending to 
 if (strtok(NULL, " ") != NULL) { //skip the part until a space appears
      continue;
     } else {
      break;
     }
did not help at all sadly.

Comment: What is `fileText`? Is it one line or the whole file?

Comment: FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
char *fileText = (char*) calloc(255, sizeof(char));
while (fgets(fileText, 255, file)) {

sorry I cant seem to highlight the code in the comments.
If i print fileText it shows me a single line.